# How to draw the poly line with directions using data from api in arcore?

Tags: java, android

How to draw the polyline with directions in arcore using below link

[this Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=12.8673542%2C80.2263797&destination=12.8678%2C80.2257293&key=AIzaSyD7rCvtQxAnej-1SdFj7H6ZKnTmyOTs2cQ)

Comment: Parse ur data and and get latitude and longitude from it and draw a polyline

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want syntax for ar code

Comment: Can u please any one tell me, compass sensor is compulsory to set navigation in arcore in android